# Wordpress upgrading plugin, does it delete content

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a basic question I could not find the answer to. I have a CF7 plugin which is configured with two forms. However there is some additional functionality I would like in the new version. If I upgrade the plugin will it overwrite the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I use CF7 as well.  All the data stays.

Comment: I do not see an "upgrade" button under the plugin. I am using 3.0.2. I would like to upgrade to 3.7.x. Can I simply reupload the zip directory?

Comment: There SHOULD be one of those "A new version is available 'Update Now'" things underneath the plugin description in the Plugins section of WP.  If not, then yes, you can refresh the files in the 'plugins' dir with the contents of the ZIP.

Comment: Hm, for some reason there isnt. So I sohuld just click 'add new" under plugins to upload new version of contact form 7?

Comment: No.  If you have access to the filesystem (FTP), just replace the contents of /wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7 with the contents of the ZIP file.  The zip file contents should look like: Admin, images, includes, languages, modules, license.txt, readme.txt, settings.php, uninstall.php, and wp-contact-form-7.php.  All those files go into the folder I posted above REPLACING what is currently there.

Comment: I dont think I have access to the FTP. I guess I could manually replace the files in the edit mode.

Comment: When you don't have FTP, updating manually could take a long time, depending on how many files you are updating.  There are some good File Manager plugins for WordPress that you might want to look into.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had to upgrade wordpress and then deploy a new versions of the plugin.